# Material Design Icons code

Tags: android, mobile, svg, icons, material-design

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<DrawerItemModel> mDrawerItems;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public DrawerAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mDrawerItems = getTravelDummyList();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mDrawerItems.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.list_view_item_navigation_drawer_travel, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dividerTop = (View) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.divider_top);
        holder.icon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.dividerBottom = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider_bottom);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    DrawerItemModel item = mDrawerItems.get(position);

    holder.icon.setText(item.getIconRes());
    holder.title.setText(item.getText());

    if (position != 0)
        holder.dividerTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return convertView;
}
public static ArrayList<DrawerItemModel> getTravelDummyList() {
    ArrayList<DrawerItemModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(0,0,  "Monuments", R.string.app_name));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(1,00, "Hotels", R.string.material_icon_sleep));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(2, 1, "Restaurants", R.string.material_icon_eat));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(3, 2, "Sport et Loisirs", R.string.material_icon_play));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(4, 3, "Shopping", R.string.material_icon_shop));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(5, 4, "Méteo", R.string.material_icon_star));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(6, 5, "Notes", R.string.material_icon_message));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(6, 5, "Photos et Videos", R.string.material_icon_video));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(7, 6, "Circuit Touristique", R.string.fontello_search));
    list.add(new DrawerItemModel(7, 6, "Recherche", R.string.material_icon_image_box));
    return list;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView icon;
    public/* Roboto */TextView title;
    public View dividerTop;
    public View dividerBottom;

}
```

}

String.xml

```
<!-- Material Design Icons -->
<string name="material_icon_bike">&#xe915;</string>
<string name="material_icon_go">&#xea04;</string>
<string name="material_icon_sleep">&#xe9c2;</string>
<string name="material_icon_eat">&#xeac6;</string>
<string name="material_icon_play">&#xe831;</string>
<string name="material_icon_drink">&#xea08;</string>
<string name="material_icon_party">&#xe937;</string>
```

What is the meaning of these String`&#xea08;  &#xe937; &#xeac6; ...` 
And How String `&#xea08` Becomes icon ?

I have a Font File (MaterialDesignIcons.ttf) in the assets/font  ??

I know not what is the principle of this method   ?

I know not what is the principle of this method   ?

Comment: `&#xea08;  &#xe937; &#xeac6; ` these are just strings. if you want to change the colors of those Go to `colors.xml` in `res` folder then change.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
watch update :)

Comment: see my answer below for your update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How String `&#xea08;` Becomes icon ?

Strings can become icons, ( :) ) Its String encoding Techniques, here HTML Entity (hex) encoding .  There are lot of encoding techniques.

Let say when you type `:)` in your smartphone then become smile emoji, there also encoding play a role.

You can find list of these symbols in  [Unique Characters list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm)

> I have a Font File (MaterialDesignIcons.ttf) in the assets/font ??

If I understand correctly, your are asking put .ttf file in font folder ?

There is no  relation  between this .ttf to those icons.

> I know not what is the principle of this method ?

Hope you get the principle by seeing the list of [Unique Characters list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm)

[image]

Note: if you are thinking  to change the color of those icons, you need to find out their string values